# ¿Sabeis como acceder mediante Google App Script a las filas resultantes de aplicar un filtro en una spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Buenas, quiero acceder a las filas resultantes de aplicar un filtro en una hoja spreadsheet pero me es imposible, no consigo hacerlo de ninguna manera, siempre me coge todas. Me ha parecido leer en algunas paginas que de momento no había manera (entradas de hace tiempo) pero no sé si ahora ya se puede hacer de alguna manera, yo al menos no he encontrado la forma. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una buena pregunta incluye información sobre la búsqueda/investigación realizada por el autor de la misma. Sería bueno que hicieras el esfuerzo por encontrar alguna página representativa de los que te "ha parecido leer", verificar si hay alguna actualización o una página similar mas reciente. También sería bueno que revisaras la documentación. Si tienes dificultadas para entenderla porque está en inglés no hay problema, pero sería bueno que hicieras el intento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he conseguido, aunque no será la manera más usual me ha servido para lo que quería. Lo que hago es antes de procesar la hoja la selecciono entera y aplico un color especifico de background a todas las filas, por suerte Google Spreadsheet sólo lo aplica a las filas resultantes de aplicar el filtro. Por tanto al procesar la hoja lo único que hago es preguntar por el color de fondo de cada fila y así sé las que son resultado del filtro. Al final del proceso vuelvo a dejar todas las filas con el color de fondo original. Ya os digo que seguramente no sea la manera más usual pero me ha servido y mientras Google no ofrezca funciones para acceder a los filtros...

```
function docReport() {
  try {
    splashScreen("Generando informe...");    
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();    
    var numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
    var numberOfRows = activeSheet.getLastRow(); 
    var activeRow, rowRange;
    var titleRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues();

    //Set los fondos a otro color para identificar las líneas a las líneas que tienen filtro
    activeSheet.setActiveSelection("2:" + activeSheet.getLastRow()).setBackground("#fffff9"); 

    var docReport =  DocumentApp.create(REPORT_FILE_NAME);
    var bodyReport = docReport.getBody();
    bodyReport.setAttributes(stylePage);

    for (var row = 2; row <= numberOfRows; row++) { //Empieza en 2 ya que no incluyo la fila de los títulos
      rowRange = activeSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numberOfColumns);
      if (rowRange.getBackground() == "#fffff9") { //If it has #fffff9 background, it means that it is a filtered row
        activeSheet.setActiveSelection(row + ":" + row).setBackground("#ffffff"); //Volvemos a dejar los fondos en blanco
        activeRow = rowRange.getValues();
        if (!isEmpty(activeRow[0], numberOfColumns)) {
          var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(IMG);
          bodyReport.appendParagraph("").addPositionedImage(image).setHeight(100).setWidth(98).setLayout(DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.WRAP_TEXT);
          bodyReport.appendParagraph("          S.J.").setAttributes(styleTextBlue); 
          bodyReport.appendParagraph(DATE_REPORT + "\r\n\r\n").setAttributes(styleDate); 

          for (var col = 1; col < numberOfColumns; col++) { //Ignoramos la columna 1 que es el contador
            if (activeRow[0][col] != "") { //Si el valor es vacio no lo imprimimos
              if (col == COLUMN_NORMA)
                bodyReport.appendParagraph(String(activeRow[0][col]).trim()).setAttributes(styleTextNorma); //Incluimos contenido
              else { 
                bodyReport.appendParagraph(titleRow[0][col]).setAttributes(styleTitle); //Incluimos título
                bodyReport.appendParagraph(String(activeRow[0][col]).trim()).setAttributes(styleText); //Incluimos contenido
              }
              bodyReport.appendParagraph("");
            }
          }
          bodyReport.appendPageBreak(); 
        }
      }
    } 
    activeSheet.setActiveSelection("2:" + activeSheet.getLastRow()).setBackground("#ffffff"); //Volvemos a dejar los fondos en blanco menos primera fila
    bodyReport.appendPageBreak();     
    docReport.saveAndClose();
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), "Informe " + REPORT_FILE_NAME + " generado", 
                      'Se ha creado un nuevo informe "' + REPORT_FILE_NAME + '" en su unidad Google Drive: \n\r' + docReport.getUrl());   
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Se ha creado un nuevo informe "' + REPORT_FILE_NAME + '" en su unidad Google Drive \r\n');
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log("ERROR in function createPdf \r\nMessage: " + e.message + "\r\nFile gs: " + e.fileName + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber)
    Logger.log("\r\nUser: " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + ", Date: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMMdd'_'HH:mm:ss"));
    MailApp.sendEmail(EMAIL_DEV, SUBJECT_MAIL, Logger.getLog());   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Según tengo entendido aún no es posible. La alternativa es que emules los criterios del filtro usando JavaScript.

## Explicación

El [servicio Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) de Google Apps Script aún no cuenta con clases para los filtros ni métodos para obtener los resultados de los mismos. Cabe mencionar que [Sheets API 4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) si cuenta con métodos para los filtros tanto básicos como para las vistas de filtro, pero estos son para modificar los filtros en sí, no para obtener los resultados que estos devuelven en la interfaz de usuario.

De [Updating spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate), traducción al español de los títulos es mía,

> ### Object (Objeto)
>
> Filters ([filter
>   views](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#filterview) & the [basic
>   filter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#basicfilter))
>
> ### Add duplicate (Agregar duplicado)
>
> [AddFilterViewRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addfilterviewrequest)
>   [DuplicateFilterViewRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#duplicatefilterviewrequest)
>
> ### Update / Set (Actualizar / establecer)
>
> [UpdateFilterViewRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatefilterviewrequest)
>   [SetBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setbasicfilterrequest)
>
> ### Delete (Borrar)
>
> [ClearBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#clearbasicfilterrequest)